# Jquery Search Index returns -1 when the string found

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ibm-mobilefirst

I have downloaded the FormBasedAuthentication Project sample from IBM Worklight 6.1 source. In that example, the challenge handler is checking for the string **j_security_check**, the code to check the string is,

```
var indicatorIdx = response.responseText.search('j_security_check');
```

where response is the JSON Object which is sent from the server, and responseText is one of the key in that JSON Object.

I am clear with the flow of the sample and everything. But i need to know the reason why it returns -1 when the string is found in the response, and returns the length of the responseText when it doesn't has the string.

Comment: post what is `response.responseText`

Comment: try response.responseText.search(/j_security_check/i); i am thinking may be case problem

Comment: Ok, i will try and update soon.

Comment: J_security_check is found on challenge and response is empty on success, and not the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

The response is opposite to your observation. Function returns -1 on missing text, as expected.

Here is the documentation for the method isCustomResponse:

**In most cases, you call this method to test whether there is a custom challenge to be handled in the response.**

In this case, you have a challenge in the form of form based authentication.